# Find non-duplicate items between two arrays with Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, find

I have the following task: 
There are 2 one dimensional arrays of integers between -20000000 and 20000000. Some of the numbers that are contained in the first array are also contained in the second array. I have to find all the numbers that are contained in the first array but are not contained in the second array. i have to use Java as a language

Here are the arrays

[1, 652 ,5, 15, 385, 4 , 55, 666, 13]

[2, 4658, 9, 55, -588, 10, 1083, 17]

Any Ideas how to find it ?

EDIT:

Here is the final code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Values {
public static void main (String[] argv) {

int[] Array1 = new int[] {1,652,5,15,385,4,55,666,13};
int[] Array2 = new int[] {2, 4658, 9, 55, -588, 10, 1083, 17};
int calculateResult = 0;
boolean contains = false;
int mod = 123456789; 
int modSum = 0;

List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<Array1.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<Array2.length; j++) {
            if(Array1[i]==Array2[j]) {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!contains) {
            results.add(Array1[i]);
        }
        else {
            contains = false;
        }
    }
    // calculate the result
    for (int i : results) {
        calculateResult  += i;
    }
    // Print Results
    System.out.println(results);
    System.out.println(calculateResult);
}}
```

Now I'm trying to load Arrays from .csv file. Any ideas ?

Comment: what do you have so far? 
have you tried something?

please show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
    int[] Array1 = new int[] {1,652,5,15,385,4,55,666,13};
    int[] Array2 = new int[] {2,4658,9,55,-588,10,1083,17};
    boolean contains = false;
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    for(int i=0; i<Array1.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<Array2.length; j++) {
            if(Array1[i]==Array2[j]) {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!contains) {
            results.add(Array1[i]);
        }
        else{
            contains = false;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(results);
```

output:

```
[1, 652, 5, 15, 385, 4, 666, 13]
```

i hope this is what are you looking for.

Comment: You should break your loop after `contains = true;`, so it can save time from comparing other element of 2nd loop to parent loop's element.

Comment: Yes it is, now I'm trying to get the sum of results

Answer (score 0):

check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)
So, answer = (A - B) + (B - A)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this question have negative votes, it is actually very interesting.

Look below which may work for you, you only need to take list instead of array

```
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(3);
        l1.add(5);
        l1.add(7);
        l1.add(8);

        l2.add(2);
        l2.add(3);
        l2.add(4);
        l2.add(7);

        l2.retainAll(l1);  //Now l2 have only common elements of both list this is an optional this will work well when there are thousands of element otherwise only do remove all
        l1.removeAll(l2);  //Here magic happens this will remove common element from l1 so l1 will have only elements what are not in l2

        for(Integer v: l1){
            System.out.println(v);
        }
```

**Output:**

```
1
5
8
```

Comment: The question probably has negative votes because the OP does not show any understanding of what he is trying to accomplish. And technically the correct answer to his question would be "Yes"... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take the first array, and, for each element of it, if this isn't an element of the second array, then take it as good otherwise discard it.

Now you have just to study how to write it in java language!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this.

```
Integer[] array1  = {1, 652 ,5, 15, 385, 4 , 55, 666, 13};
Integer[] array2 ={2, 4658, 9, 55, -588, 10, 1083, 17};
List<Integer> list=  new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array1));
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(list);
set.removeAll(Arrays.asList(array2));

System.out.println(set);
```