# CSV file to Array in java. Any ideas?

Tags: java, list, names

I'm trying to load arrays from CSV file. Here is the code [Find non-duplicate items between two arrays with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401618/find-non-duplicate-items-between-two-arrays-with-java)

Will this work ?

```
    ReadFile file = new ReadFile( file_name );
    String[ ] aryLines = file.OpenFile( );
```

Comment: use Jackson CsvMapper

Comment: what is your exact issue how to read CSV or duplicate elements , because i don't see your working

Answer (score 1):

Try this to read csv:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

And then to remove duplicates in lists A and B, you probably want to use a Set (non-duplicate collection)

```
List<Integer> A = readFromFile("a.csv"); // Arrays.asList(1,2,4)
List<Integer> B = readFromFile("b.csv"); // Arrays.asList(1,2,3)

Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>() // will sort for you as well
set.addAll(A)
set.addAll(B)
```