# Java: how to compare two int[] arrays for non duplicate elements?

Tags: java, arrays, int, duplicates

How do you compare two int[] arrays for duplicate elements?

For example: `int countDifference(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB)` that takes as input two sorted arrays of numbers, and returns the number of numbers that occur in only one of the two arrays.

Example: countdifference([2,4,6,8], [3,4,6,9]) returns **`4`** because `4` and `6` are duplicates, remaining numbers are `2`, `8`, `3` and `9`.

I got a method that counts distinct elements to work for one array, but not non duplicate elements for two arrays.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class countDistinctArray {

  public static int distinctNumberOfItems(int[] array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
      return array.length;
    }

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i : array) {
      set.add(i);
    }
    return set.size();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int array[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 4, 6, 9 };
    System.out.println(distinctNumberOfItems(array));
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do it the same way as in the `distinctNumberOfItems` method. Just add a  second for loop where you remove elements from the set again.

Comment: how would I start doing that? where do i place my for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find non-duplicate items between two arrays with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401618/find-non-duplicate-items-between-two-arrays-with-java)

Comment: As you said, `4` and `6` are duplicates, which means that `2`, `3`, `8`, and `9` are non-duplicates, so the correct answer would be a count of **4**, not 3.

Comment: Yes sorry, it returns 4 not 3! You are a genius!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binary search to compare arrays and find differences. You need to do that comparison as two-way(<-  ->) like:

```
array1 --> array2  and  array2 --> array1
```

Because you need to sum up differences of sets. Let A and B our sets, we need to find:

```
(A-B) U (B-A)
```

The binary search solution is below. Complexity of that algorithm is O(log n)

```
private static int getDifferenceBetweenTwoArray(int[] array1 , int[] array2)
{
    int differenceCount = 0;
    //if you dont want to sort your original arrays, create temporary arrays
    int temp1[] = Arrays.copyOf(array1 , array1.length);
    int temp2[] = Arrays.copyOf(array2 , array2.length);
    Arrays.sort(temp1);
    Arrays.sort(temp2);

    for(Integer i : temp1)
    {
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(temp2, i) < 0)
            differenceCount++;
    }
    for(Integer i: temp2)
    {
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(temp1, i) < 0)
            differenceCount++;
    }   

    return differenceCount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the answer I am looking for! What does < 0 do? And what's the worst case time complexity for your algorithm?

Comment: @EstelleVeneer In java docs it says: "Arrays.binarySearch() method returns index of the search key, if it is contained in the array, else it returns (-(insertion point) - 1)."  It means; if your array doesn't contain search key this method certainly  returns a negative integer. This is why I used < 0. Worst case time complexity of this algorithm is O(log n) .

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
     int countDifference(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB){
         int count=0;         
         for(int i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<arrayB.length){
             if(arrayA[i]==arrayB[j])
             count++;
             else
             continue;}} }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, would be to use either the [`removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) or [`retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Another way would be to iterate the arrays in parallel, without using `Set`.

For easy of use, the first two methods will use this helper:

```
private static Set<Integer> asSet(int[] array) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i : array)
        set.add(i);
    return set;
}
```

Implementation using `removeAll()`:

```
public static int countDifference(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    // Find distinct elements in array1 that doesn't exist in array2
    Set<Integer> distinct1 = asSet(array1);
    distinct1.removeAll(asSet(array2));

    // Find distinct elements in array2 that doesn't exist in array1
    Set<Integer> distinct2 = asSet(array2);
    distinct2.removeAll(asSet(array1));

    return distinct1.size() + distinct2.size();
}
```

If the arrays themselves are guaranteed not to contain duplicates, then `retainAll()` can find the common values:

```
public static int countDifference(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    Set<Integer> common = asSet(array1);
    common.retainAll(asSet(array2));
    return array1.length + array2.length - 2 * common.size();
}
```

Neither of the above implementations rely on arrays being sorted. To eliminate the overhead of creating sets and the boxing of all the values, you can use the sorting of the arrays, and iterate them in parallel:

```
public static int countDifference(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0, count = 0, val;
    while (idx1 < array1.length || idx2 < array2.length) {
        if (idx1 == array1.length) {
            val = array2[idx2];
            count++;
        } else if (idx2 == array2.length) {
            val = array1[idx1];
            count++;
        } else {
            val = Math.min(array1[idx1], array2[idx2]);
            if (array1[idx1] != val || array2[idx2] != val)
                count++;
        }
        while (idx1 < array1.length && array1[idx1] == val)
            idx1++; // skipping 0 to many instances of val in array1
        while (idx2 < array2.length && array2[idx2] == val)
            idx2++; // skipping 0 to many instances of val in array2
    }
    return count;
}
```

This would be the fastest and most memory-efficient implementation.

---

**Thought**

It could be argued that `countDifference` would consider inputs `3,5,5,7` and `3,5,7` to have 1 difference. If so, then any use of `Set` is wrong, and the last method should replace the inner `while` loops with `if` statements, or use a simpler implementation like this:

```
public static int countDifference(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0, count = 0;
    while (idx1 < array1.length && idx2 < array2.length) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(array1[idx1], array2[idx2]);
        if (cmp != 0)
            count++;
        if (cmp <= 0)
            idx1++;
        if (cmp >= 0)
            idx2++;
    }
    return count + (array1.length - idx1) + (array2.length - idx2);
}
```

Personally, I consider this the right solution, but it depends on how repeated values in an array should be handled. This is the best implementation if there will be no repeats, or if repeats are considered distinct, e.g. like that value `5` is counted as a difference in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not a concern and using java's data structures like hashset is allowed, and given that numbers in the arrays are in ascending order, then here is a simple solution:
first we put all the elements of the second array into a hashset, then we loop through the first array to see how many elements are common to both arrays, then we return the total count of elements in two arrays, minus those common elements

```
import java.util.*;

public class CountDistinctArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrayOne = new int[]{-1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8};
        int[] arrayTwo = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        System.out.println(distinctNumberOfItems(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
    }

    public static int distinctNumberOfItems(int[] first, int[] second) {
        Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int num : second) {
            numbers.add(num);
        }

        int commonElements = 0;
        for (int num : first) {
            if (numbers.contains(num)) {
                commonElements++;
            }
        }

        return first.length + second.length - commonElements * 2;
    }
```

}